# Вопрос по Generic-методу и ограничению типов в C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Хочу сделать примерно такой Generic-метод:

```
private static TOut? ConvertWithNullCheck<TOut>(string field, Func<string, TOut> convertMethod) where TOut : struct
{
    return field == null ? null : (TOut?)convertMethod(field);
}
```

Идея метода такова, что перед вызовом конвертера входное значение `string field` проверяется на `null`. И если оно равно `null`, то метод должен вернуть `null`.

Сейчас он работает только для значимых типов. Однако я хочу, чтобы он также работал и для ссылочных типов. Например, так работает:

```
public static int? ConvertModelId(string modelId)
{
    var result = ConvertWithNullCheck(modelId, ConvertModelIdCore);
    return result;
}

private static int ConvertModelIdCore(string modelIdField)
{
    //..
}
```

А так не работает (и это логично, потому что string - ссылочный тип):

```
public static string ConvertCellId(string cellId)
{
    var result = ConvertWithNullCheck(cellId, ConvertCellId);
    return result;
}

private static string ConvertCellIdCore(string cellIdField)
{
    //...
}
```

Есть ли какой-то способ сделать правильное ограничение для этого generic-метода? Можно использовать версии языка C# 6.0+

Comment: Можно, конечно, сделать два generic-метода (один для значимых, другой для ссылочных), но все же, может быть, можно как-то сделать один метод?

Comment: `И если оно равно null, то метод должен вернуть null.` - изначально неверный подход. От `null` надо избавляться при первой же возможности, а не гонять его через цепочку вызовов методов.

Comment: @Bulson как вы предлагаете сделать? Я по уникальному индексу поля из массива достаю значение `string field`. Если там нет значения, то `field == null` будет. И мне нужно 25 свойств бизнес-модели засетать (все свойства - nullable). И что, мне перед вызовом каждого метода ковертации писать `if (field != null) businessModel.Property = Convert(field)`? Код разрастется в раза 3. Мой же подход сокращает код и делает его более читабельным

Comment: Сообщение выше - лишь мое субъективное мнение. Оно может отличаться от реальности

Comment: По поводу возвращения null [см. хотя бы такое объяснение](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwycPnpp6uQ). `по уникальному индексу поля из массива достаю значение` - вот там и надо присваивать либо `String.Empty` либо какое-то типовое значение. Разработку лучше вести в парадигме TDD тогда можно избежать многих изначально кривых решений.

Comment: в C#8 добавили `constraint` для обозначения не нулевых типов `notnull`, однако для возвращения `nullable` типа, все еще недостаточно добавить `?` к возвращающему значению. Судя по всему все заработает в C#9 https://stackoverflow.com/q/55975211/2881286